# Renaming an li in ul using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I like to know how to rename a node in a tree dynamically. I think i need a textbox to come over a particular li need to rename. After when user clicks enter need to change as name of that node. Can any one help me to rename a node in my tree which is shown below.. I need it with javascript.

My dynamically created code for tree is something like

```
<ul id="browser" class="filetree treeview">
<li class="collapsable">
    <div class="hitarea collapsable-hitarea">
    </div>
    <span class="folder">Chat</span><ul>
        <li class="last">
            <div class="hitarea collapsable-hitarea">
            </div>
            <span class="folder">Chat</span><ul>
                <li class="collapsable">
                    <div class="hitarea collapsable-hitarea">
                    </div>
                    <span class="folder">ChatHistory</span><ul>
                        <li class="last">
                            <div class="hitarea collapsable-hitarea">
                            </div>
                            <span class="file">ChatHistory</span> </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="last">
                    <div class="hitarea collapsable-hitarea">
                    </div>
                    <span class="folder">CompletedChats</span><ul>
                        <li class="last">
                            <div class="hitarea collapsable-hitarea">
                            </div>
                            <span class="file">CompletedChat</span> </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: kindly post some code in here

Comment: code, and purpose please, why you want to change <li> to something else?

Comment: Tree is created dynamcally.. If user need to change the name of a node  he can by renaming a node.Thats the purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't need browser full compatibility (not compatible with IE<8 :http://caniuse.com/#feat=contenteditable), you can try using contenteditable attribute :

```
<span class="file" contenteditable="true">ChatHistory</span>
```

Then, you probably need to get this value in javascript and send it to a server. That's another question, but at least i can show you how you can get depth of your node based on `ul` context (`jQuery` required for easiest implementation) and your text value :

```
// The event could be keypress too...
// But blur event is less agressive especially if you need to send requests
$("span[contenteditable='true']").on("blur", function () {
    var value = $(this).text();
    var depth = $(this).parents("ul").length;
    console.log(depth, value);
});
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/Akaryatrh/M5WUv/